# What's the difference between accessing a class' attribute via the class' name vs classmethod?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was asked during an interview what is the difference between the following two ways to access a class' attribute:

```
class Klass:
    x = 10

    @staticmethod
    def foo():
        return Klass.x

    @classmethod
    def bar(cls):
        return cls.x
```

PS: I know the difference between `classmethod` and `staticmethod`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between staticmethod and classmethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod)

Comment: no) I wasn't asking what's the difference between classmethod and staticmethod)

Comment: @IvanDives What are you asking then? `what is the difference between the following two ways to access class attribute` Isn't this your question?

Comment: Just a hunch : I'd say that it will have impacts when you are taking class inheritance in mind... (The second way of accessing arguments would probably allow you to access attributes of other inherited/parent classes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using cls would also work with inheritance,

```
class Klass2(Klass):
  x = 5

print(Klass2().foo())
10
print(Klass2().bar())
5
```

Though there might be more differences

Comment: Both `static-` and `classmethod` are (usually) called ***on the class***. So change `Klass2()` to `Klass2`